# Redhat: php53-common conflicts with php-common

Tags: php, rhel, rhel5

In Redhat 5.10, when I do yum update, I got php53-common conflicts with php-common.
Currently, (I have cli php 5.3.3 installed)

There is a solution for centos: http://www.howtoforge.com/centos-5.6-php53-common-conflicts-with-php-common, but I am not sure I can use it in redhat.

I did a `yum update --skip-broken`, but still no help.

**Update**:

**A non-working-for-me-solution**: http://www.ehowstuff.com/work-around-for-error-php53-odbc64-conflicts-with-php53-odbc/

**Update 1**:

I try to remove php53-common, then many dependent php53 packages (e.g. php53-cli, php53-bcmath, etc) will be removed as well. Do I need to install php-cli, php-bcmath, etc individually?

Comment: @kraysak, I saw it and I included it in my post. Does it work with redhat? I can try it, but I don't want to break the server.

Comment: aww sorry, didnt read the centos part.. maybe it work

Comment: http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-fix-php53-common-conflicts-with-php-common-on-linux/ and here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100936/phpmyadmin-in-linux-installation